# Creating a method to increase 4 family members age by 1

Tags: c#, methods, parameter-passing

I am trying to create a method that increases the family age by one. Passing arguments to method is extremely difficult for me, especially with this problem. I believe there is a better way of doing this, but this is the only way that can come to mind. I am currently having trouble trying to display all 4 of the families age into one label, after their age is increased by one. This is currently what I have:

```
// Create a method using the increment operator that increates the age of 4 family members by 1
private void TotalAge (int age1/*, int age2, int age3, int age4*/)
{
    age1++;
   /* age2++;
    age3++;
    age4++; */
}

private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Variables to hold family member ages 
    int member1 = 0, member2 = 0, member3 = 0, member4 = 0;

    // Conver the ages into a string, using tryparse method
    if (int.TryParse(ageTextBox1.Text, out member1))
    {
        if (int.TryParse(ageTextBox2.Text, out member2))
        {
            if (int.TryParse(ageTextBox3.Text, out member3))
            {
                if (int.TryParse(ageTextBox4.Text, out member4))
                {
                    displayAge.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalAge(member1))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than saving the Age, save the DOB so you can do simple subtraction to show the correct age at any moment - even as a calculated property!  Its almost always a bad idea to save a bit of data that is easily calculated

Answer (score 1):

you should create a `FamilyMember` class that will contain all the properties of a family member (age, name, etc.) then you simply pass a list or an array of family members to a function that will increment in 1  the age of every `FamilyMember` in the array.

```
Public class FamilyMember 
{
    public string Name {private set; get;}
    public int Age { private set; get; }

    public FamilyMember(string name, int age)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
        }
    public void IncrementAge()
    {
        Age++;
    }
}

Public void IncrementAgeOfFamilyMembers(List<FamilyMember> FamilyMembers)
{
     foreach (var fmember in FamilyMembers)
         fmember.IncrementAge();
}
```

if you want it to be for exactly 4 family members just change the `List<FamilyMember>` to `FamilyMember[4]` (but then you should check for nulls)